# How to filter based on column values in other rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I didn't know a better way to word the title question.

Here's the sample table:

```
| email | subscription ref num |  state   |
|-------|----------------------|----------|
| 1@1.1 |         10           | inactive |
| 2@2.2 |         11           | inactive |
| 1@1.1 |         12           | inactive |
| 1@1.1 |         13           |  active  |
| 3@3.3 |         14           |  active  |
etc
```

I want to get all emails from the table that do not have an active subscription. I cannot just filter `WHERE state=inactve` because look at email address `1@1.1`. That user has both old inactive subscriptions, but also a currently active one.

So for this sample db, I would only want to return email `2@2.2`. Hope that makes sense.

Can someone help me with the correct query to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...that do not have an active subscription:

```
select distinct email
from yourTable
where email not in 
     (select email from yourTable where state = 'active')
```

the query explains itself: select distinct emails that don't have active state in any row.

ADDED: You can create an index on state column in mySql. Also, this could be faster:

```
select distinct email
from yourTable
where not exists 
     (select * from yourTable as helper 
      where state = 'active' and helper.email = yourTable.email )
```

Comment: This seems to work and I very much like the readability. But phpMyAdmin is slow to respond for some reason, showing Query took 0.1292 seconds

Comment: you should create an index in 'state' column of your table, in mySql. Or you could try the second option I'm adding to my answer...

Comment: 3500 rows. I don't know what it means to create an index. The 2nd option performs about the same: Query took 0.1342 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way...

```
select email 
from sampletable 
group by email
having max(state) = 'inactive' and min(state) = 'inactive'
```

Comment: downvoter..you should be able to explain the reason for downvoting the answer

Comment: This seems to work, and fast Query took 0.0203 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having` clause to filter the group. Try this

```
select email 
from yourtable 
group by email
having count(case when state ='inactive' then 1 end) = 1 
   and count(*)= 1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/295e0/2)

Comment: this won't work when there are 2 rows with `inactive` state for a email

Comment: If such scenario is possible then we can add `distinct` in `Count`

Comment: sorry i left that case out, yes 2 inactive rows are definitely possible

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.email = x.email 
            AND y.state = 'active' 
          WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select email 
from table
group by email
having max(state) = 'inactive' 
  and count(distinct state) = 1
```

or without grouping

```
select t1.email
from table t1
where t1.state = 'inactive'
  and not exists(
    select 1
    from table t2
    where t2.email = t1.email
      and t2.status = 'active'
  )
```